# Clearing A PrintDocument

Tags: c#, printing

I have a method that does printing of multiple documents (PrintIts). It works pretty well except after the first print is complete, the second print includes the first print on top of it.  Like there are two layers on the second print.  The third print, includes the first and second on top of it (as if each print was on a transparent layer).  Basically what I'm looking to be able to do is clear the Document's contents with each print.

```
static private PrintDocument Document = new PrintDocument();

static public void PrintIts(IEnumerable<string> inputStrings){
    foreach(string inputString in inputStrings){
        PrintIt(inputString);
    }
}

static public void PrintIt(string inputString){
    Document.PrintPage += (sender, e) => Document_PrintText(e, inputString);
    Document.Print();
}

static private void Document_PrintText(PrintPageEventArgs e, string inputString) {
    e.Graphics.DrawString(inputString, new Font("Courier New", 12), Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
}
```

I've tried accomplishing this by doing the following:

```
static public void PrintIt(string inputString){
    Document.PrintPage += (sender, e) => Document_PrintText(e, inputString);
    Document.EndPrint += Document_Clear; //<- I added this extra line
    Document.Print();
}

static private void Document_Clear(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e){
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
}
```

The error that I'm getting when I try doing this is:

> No overload for 'Document_Clear'
>   matches delegate
>   'System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventHandler'.

I'm pretty new to writing my own event methods (I usually do winForm development, and these are added automatically).  If you can correct my method, or suggest a different one for accomplishing my goal, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I've not used PrintDocument before so not sure if this is correct but have you tried making the object local instead of global. So you create a new one everytime PrintIt is called.

Comment: This makes things more complicated.  I won't get into it, but I'd rather just go ahead with what my question is asking.  (Sorry I don't want to share all of my code, thanks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code

```
static private void Document_Clear(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e){
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
}
```

should read

```
static private void Document_Clear(object sender, PrintEventArgs e){
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
}
```

Ok the last thing I can suggest is to clear the graphics inside the printpage lambda.

```
Document.PrintPage += (sender, e) => { e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White); Document_PrintText(e, inputString);
```

Comment: I'm getting 'PrintEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Graphics'.  Do I need to add a reference or something to make this work?

Comment: I would then use the example that msarchet suggested. Simply instantiate a new PrintDocument on each print. If you have to use the EndPrint event, simply use this line in the EndPrint event handler Document = new PrintDocument;

Comment: I can't reveal my code, but doing this would actually make things more complex.  If I can figure out how to clear things, that would be preferable.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok the last thing I can suggest is to clear the graphics inside the printpage lambda. Document.PrintPage += (sender, e) => { e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White); Document_PrintText(e, inputString);. this is of course assuming that each page has its own graphics instance, I.e. you wont be clearing the other pages graphics. Im not too sure how PrintDocs work in that regard

Comment: Craigt, that worked perfectly, thanks.  I'll be adding that to your solution so others can find it more easily. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a new print document before each print?

So in `PrintIt`

```
static public void PrintIt(string inputString){    
    Document = new PrintDocument();
    Document.PrintPage += (sender, e) => Document_PrintText(e, inputString);
    Document.Print();
}
```

You're probably over complicating this.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change "PrintPageEventArgs e" into "PrintEventArgs e" in your Document_Clear method, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printeventhandler.aspx

Comment: I'm getting this error: 'PrintEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Graphics'